# CGImageDestinationFinalize fails, sometimes crashes

Tags: ios, swift, image-processing, cgimage

I'm trying to save some photos after capture. But while saving `CGImageDestinationFinalize` fails & mostly crashes.

```
let cgImage: CGImage...

let data: CFMutableData = CFDataCreateMutable(nil, 0)
// Older phones can't save to HEIC, so falling back to JPEG.
let destination
            = CGImageDestinationCreateWithData(data, "public.heic" as CFString, 1, nil)
              ?? CGImageDestinationCreateWithData(data, kUTTypeJPEG as CFString, 1, nil)!

CGImageDestinationAddImage(destination, cgImage, metadata)
NSLog(log: "Check #1") // This line executes
let _ = CGImageDestinationFinalize(destination) // Crashes here (fails/ returns false)
NSLog(log: "Check #2") // not executed
PHPhotoLibrary.save(photo: data as Data, success: success)
```

It crashes with:

> Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue

I tested it on *iPhone7+* & *iPhoneXS*, it's working. But crashing on my *iPhoneX*. All of them running *iOS12.2*.
While [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37913070/9014860) says it was a *known issue in iOS 9 that has been resolved in iOS 10*.

It does not tell the reason or give me a stack trace. Any ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: check for destination != nil

Comment: guard CGImageDestinationFinalize(destination) else { // log or return }

Comment: @user3344236 still crashes